# Using wireshark to monitor and compare packets sent to Zebra Printer?

Tags: wireshark

I have a odd problem with a Zebra printer that I am using.  It is supposed to print at 2 inches per second.  I have set this on my control panel (it is set up as a windows printer), as well as setting it under the Zebra PrinterServer.

I use an application called CoLOS to print barcodes off of it during production, but for some reason, it keeps overwriting the 2 inches per second setting under the Zebra Net Print Server to 6 inches per second.  Their tech support basically told me it's impossible on their end because it's using windows drivers, but after testing printing other items through other applications with no issue (some of which are through CoLOS itself), nothing else triggers the printer to revert to 6 inches per second except for the only print job that matters.

I have wireshark set up to monitor connections between the server and the printer.  I have printed one good print from CoLOS that does not trigger the printer to change it's inches per second setting, and I did one print that I know triggers it (and verified it switched from 2 to 6 after).  I have the captures that have the data packets, but I can't interpret them.  Would there be a way for me to compare these/turn them into some readable format, so that I can show this to tech support?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find [this](http://I%20found%20what%20I%20needed.%20%20Using%20this%20link%20I%20was%20able%20to%20interpret%20the%20import%20first%20few%20lines%20of%20the%20ASCII%20https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) which tells me how to interpret the important first few lines of the ASCII text that was sent to the printer.  It confirmed for me that the production print job was sending ^PR6, setting the inches per second to 6, overwriting the 2 inches per second I had previously set to the printer.